# What permissions should the account for MS SQL Server Agent have?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security, permissions

I'm in a situation where I need to change the account for the Server Agent of SQL Server from `NETWORK SERVICE` to an AD domain account. All I'm doing is making the domain account sysadmin in the instance of SQL where the Server agent is. I'm not making it a Windows administrators.

There are currently jobs running there and I really don't want to make crash.

What should I take into account?

Comment: Step one, make sure you use SS Configuration Manager to make the change.  It will handle some of the security for you.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to verify that the AD account will have access to the parts of the file system that it might need.  We ran into this awhile ago, and I don't remember which jib had an issue.  Could have been backup, or something else.

If you're using SQL to connect to remote SQL Servers, then it depends on if you are using linked servers.  Linked servers use the SQL to connect to the remote server.  If you open a connection directly on the remote server, you'll need a Windows (probably) or SQL authentication login on that server

Answer (score 0):

If you have any jobs that are running SSIS packages that are accessing other servers, make sure your new account has the appropriate permissions on those servers.

For example, if SQL Server A has an SSIS package that is pulling data from a database on SQL Server B, you'll need to make sure that your new account has access to SQL Server B and permissions on that database.

Comment: Jobs should use their Proxy->Credential to authenticate to those severs. I'm worried more about if my new domain accout will have the permissions for go outside the server.